# iOS Swift: UIWebView has extremely big content

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, size, scale

I have a `UIWebView` that is loading local html, css and javascript.

The problem is that all the assets of the html projects are displayed very very big.

I've tried to play around with `webView` scale factor and nothing changes..

I've even tried this inside the `didFinishLoad`:

```
let contentSize:CGSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize
        let viewSize:CGSize = self.view.bounds.size

        let rw: CGFloat = viewSize.width / contentSize.width

        webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw
        webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw
        webView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw
```

But still, all the images are too bigggg.

Any help?

Comment: I suspect this is more likely an issue with your meta tags or CSS than the webview.

Comment: @JacobKing like what?

Comment: Well usually if an image is being sized incorrectly, it's probably due to the CSS that's styling it. For example, it might be set to be 300px wide, which on a desktop would look fine but on a mobile would be way too big. I'm not a web dev unfortunately so there is only so much I can tell you, but I believe there is a concept of 'reactive' pages that adjust their sizing to fit both desktop and mobile well.

Comment: UIWebVIew deprecated a long time ago, I advice to move forward and switch to WebKit

Comment: I need to support iOS 9

Answer (score 0):

try this code on viewdidload

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES
self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
```